# CANopen SYNC object and synchronous window length

Tags: control, control-system, can

In CANopen specification there is an object called **Communication Cycle Priod** [1006h]. This is the time interval between two consecutive SYNC objects. There is also another object called **Synchronous Window Length** [1007h]. I cannot get these two parameters real-world interpretations. This synchronous window length is for a synchronization interval between nodes? After receving a SYNC object, all nodes are used it as an trigger for update their output values and accept new input from bus? For example, if my control loop wait updated values in each 1 mS, then what should I set my 1006h and 1007h values? Is there a rule for 1006h and 1007h values?

Comment: From what I remember, window length is used together with high resolution time stamp (1013h). You set a window expressed (in microseconds I believe?) in which the sync must appear at the consumer. Similar to watchdog windows on microcontrollers.

Comment: @Lundin, Sure, you are correct. It is written in microsecond. I try to obtain that maximum number of axes at the 1 mS update time on the CANopen bus. i.e : at most how many axes can I control at 1 mS update time by using CANopen?

Comment: @Lundin, In CANbus layer [physical], one frame is about 128-bit. Add interframe spacing and some possible stuffing-bits, let say one frame is 146-bit length. Even for 1Mbps baud-rate, 6850 frame/second. In 1 mS, it would give ~6 frame. This teoretical maximum value. Assume %50 bus-loading, this gives only 3 frame within 1 mS. This is realy slow for a tightly-synchronous motion-control task, isnt it?

Comment: Your calculations seem roughly accurate for the worst case with 29 bit id, 8 bytes payload, max stuffing (see this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/423413/6102). "Slow" is highly subjective, depends on what you are trying to control. If you must have better than 1ms response time for the device, I'd say that's quite a special case. Most motion control systems work with 10ms periods. And slow humans can only start to spot latencies around roughly 150-200ms.

Comment: Btw if your bus is correctly designed, then the real-time critical data would take precedence with its low CAN identifier. Then at x% bus load you would still have the very same frame rate as you would at 0% bus load. CAN is CSMA/CA, it doesn't have packet loss due to collisions.

Comment: @Ludin, What you mean 10ms periods? If I am not wrong, there are a lot of control systems where their position control loop work @ 1 kHz. This means that control loop needs new sensor data every 1ms and produce new command every 1ms, right? Remember we have only ~3 CAN frame in 1ms even for 1Mbps. Say one frame is for feedback sensor data, one frame is for control loop command. If I have multiple axis, CAN would be seen insufficient for 1 ms cycle time? Am I wrong?

Comment: We don't design CAN systems to behave _as_ the worst case, but _with the worst case in mind_. This means that your time-critical message will have a low standard identifier. It will have as much data as needed. It will most likely not have maximum stuffing bits. It will always win bus arbitration since it is highest priority, making bus load irrelevant. Lets say you need to transfer 4 bytes of data. You have an overhead of roughly 47 bits (including intermission), then payload of 32 bits, lets say 80 bits total. At 1Mbps you can transmit that frame in 80us guaranteed "hard" real-time.

Comment: Meaning you will be able to send 12 such frames per 1ms. Guaranteed.

Comment: @Lundin, Thank you for reply. So this 12 frame per 1ms is %100 channel capacity. I am using CANopen for motion control. For one axis, I need an encoder output value, thus my controller can produce a command. So this means that I have used two frames per one axis control. I am using PDOs for both receving encoder output and sending controller command. From this view, I can control at most 6 axis with a 1ms cycle time, theoretically. So if I have a longer cycle time, for example 10 ms as you said, I can control up to 60 axes simultaneously?

Comment: Something like that. I'm guessing the SYNC object will be your deadline and each node needs to have gotten its data ahead of SYNC, with sufficient time to decode the frame before acting on it. My made-up 12 frame example is with 4 bytes payload though, sounds like you could do 16 bit resolution = 2 bytes. I have no idea what you are trying to control, but also keep in mind the bus length. 1Mbit means 40m max, with very short stubs (< 0.3m). That with ideal wiring: twisted pair, shielded, proper signal GND etc. Sounds like a strange application to fit 60 nodes within 40m.