# How can you calculate the effective transfer rate of canbus?

Tags: can, bus

The things i found out are that the baudrate and maximum bits of the message matters. But i don't understand how they exactly calculate the transfer rate.

[image: transfer rates]

Comment: Did you want average with latency and thruput reductions?  Bits/frame x frames/s gives you avg thruput.

Comment: The 'transfer rate' is actually the bitrate, maybe you are more interested in the messages for seconds or the delay to have a message delivered.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate: [How to calculate bus load of CAN bus?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/422998/how-to-calculate-bus-load-of-can-bus)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a spreadsheet to calculate the frame length for the best/worst cases.

**Standard Frame (11-bit Identifier)**

[image]

**Extended Frame (29-bit Identifier)**

[image]

Only SOF, ID, RTR, IDE, RSVD, DLC, DAT and CRC are considered for bit stuffing (the blue colored entries). Add up these bits, divide it by 5 and round the result down.

To calculate the effective number of bits of a given frame, you need to parse the bit stream (which isn't viable in most cases). Depending on the actual use-case I either work with the worst case (max number of stuffing bits), or the average of min/max.

The transfer rate is calculated as follows:

[image]

**Example**

Worst case transfer rate at 1000 kbps bitrate, 8 data bytes, standard identifier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's just about the payload vs overhead ratio.

In the example they give, which looks fairly accurate, you have 64 data bits out of 130. Which is the extreme worst case with 19 stuffing bits, which is highly unlikely.

It appears that whoever made the article considered identifier part of the payload - rightly so, since it is often used for higher layer purposes.

Then you have 64 data bits + 11 identifier bits = 75 bits payload. 75/130 = 57.69%.

So at 1Mbps, the effective transfer rate will be 577kbps. They have for some reason truncated the decimals instead of rounding them.

Comment: How they came up with the extended id calculation though, I don't know. Counting the identifier as part of the payload should make extended id more data-efficient.